# Error when Creating Email Simulation using Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, simulation, payload

I'm attempting to create a simulation email with Microsoft Graph Explorer but have encountered an error message labeled with "BadRequest." It's related to the "endUserNotification" property within the payload; the provided value does not conform to the expected schema. The error message includes the following JSON:

```json
"error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Property endUserNotification in payload has a value that does not match schema.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-11-01T05:56:30",
            "request-id": "ceccb0a9-699a-4245-a286-a77516bdfdab",
            "client-request-id": "b0c432f7-9ec1-b355-17fc-9f9c16c0609f"
        }
```

I've referred to an example from Microsoft on creating simulations, but the error persists. The example is available at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attacksimulationroot-post-simulation?view=graph-rest-1.0

**Examples**

```
Request

The following example shows a request.
HTTP

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/attackSimulation/simulations
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Graph Simulation",
  "payload@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/attacksimulation/payloads/12345678-9abc-def0-123456789a",
  "loginPage@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/attacksimulation/loginPages/1w345678-9abc-def0-123456789a",
  "landingPage@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/attacksimulation/landingPages/1c345678-9abc-def0-123456789a",
  "createdBy": {
    "email": "john@contoso.com"
  },
  "durationInDays": "3",
  "attackTechnique": "credentialHarvesting",
  "status": "scheduled",
  "includedAccountTarget": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.addressBookAccountTargetContent",
    "type": "addressBook",
    "accountTargetEmails": [
      "john@contoso.com"
    ]
  },
  "trainingSetting": {
    "settingType": "noTraining"
  },
  "endUserNotificationSetting": {
    "notificationPreference": "microsoft",
    "settingType": "noTraining",
    "positiveReinforcement": {
      "deliveryPreference": "deliverAfterCampaignEnd",
      "endUserNotification": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/attacksimulation/endUserNotifications/1ewer3678-9abc-def0-123456789a",
      "defaultLanguage": "en"
    },
    "simulationNotification": {
      "targettedUserType": "compromised",
      "endUserNotification@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/attacksimulation/endUserNotifications/12wer3678-9abc-def0-123456789a",
      "defaultLanguage": "en"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I see only one issue with `durationInDays` which should be integer not string.

Try to change

```
"durationInDays": "3",
```

to

```
"durationInDays": 3,
```

Are you sure about `simulationNotification` in `endUserNotificationSetting`? I don't see that [endUserNotificationSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/endusernotificationsetting?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource contain the property `simulationNotification`.